# Output file content with grep along with directory name

Tags: grep, find, xargs

I have something like a tree structure of directories, with some of them having inside a file named "Filename". Inside each of these files, there is some information that I would like to access after changing its "look".
Here's what I have:

```
find . - name "Filename" | xargs perl -pe ...(one liner to change "look" of file, and put info i want to grep in one line) | grep "WhatIWantToShow" | egrep "exclude|some|stuff"
```

This works fine and it outputs the info I pretended.
But I also need the directory name for each of the files found, and in which the grep was applied.

Thats now a big headache for me. Im stuck.
Would appreciate if you guys can show me some light. Thanks.

Comment: Replace `| xargs <stuff>` by `-exec <stuff> {} \; -printf '%h\n'` maybe? May require GNU `find`.

Comment: using SunOS. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving `.` in the find command `try giving the complete folder name` and check.